# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "wassail" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Tengo ciertos problemas al traducir "wassail". Se encuentra en el párrafo siguiente (extracto del juego V20 - Rites of The Blood, pág 106):

> To enact this ritual, the caster must prepare at least two other
>   vampires (of the Nosferatu, Tzimisce, or Gangrel Clans) for at least a
>   full turn of the moon, feeding them a very small amount of cursed and
>   defiled blood, and starving them to within an inch of **wassail**. These
>   individuals are tortured nightly, and various humiliations and
>   physical horrors inflicted upon them, to break their sanity and weaken
>   their body.

¿Cómo podría traducirse?

Comment: The context here does not match up with my understanding of the word [*wassail*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wassail). I presume the book is using the word with its own invented definition (something akin to starvation/death?). In which case, I'd just use *wassail*.

Comment: ¿Podrías describir con tus propias palabras qué quiere decir _wassail_? ¿Has mirado [lo que sugiere Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=wassail)? A mí no me suena de nada.

Comment: No vamos a poder traducir eso sin tener algo más de contexto. Por lo que he visto _wassail_ es algo así como un brindis o una bebida con la que se hace un brindis. Pero el libro que mencionas se enmarca en el mundo de Vampiro: La Mascarada. Muchos libros describen que para convertir a alguien en vampiro tienes que beber de su sangre hasta el borde de la muerte. Seguramente ese proceso mencione el _wassail_ de otra forma que nos ayude.

Comment: Slifer: la última edición añadiendo tanto texto no ayuda. Céntrate en explicarnos qué es para ti _wassail_ en lugar de delegar en nosotros la comprensión del concepto :) Intenta explicar el concepto, luego entre todos podremos pergeñar la búsqueda de una palabra que la defina.

Comment: @SliferDragon no sé si la descripción completa ayudará. He encontrado textos que mencionan la palabra en mayúscula: "The vampires need to be captured and driven to the edge of Wassail." Está claro que el término es importante dentro del mundo del libro, así que tendremos que buscar fuentes que expliquen qué significa en ese mundo.

Comment: @ukemi That was the correct answer! It's just untraslatable, it's called "Wassail" to a state of a vampire that goes into a perpetual frenzy for blood, converting it in a blood-controlled monster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extraído de [aquí](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Wassail):

> Wassail is the last frenzy [term describing a supernatural fight-or-flight reaction experienced by characters in Vampire: The Masquerade] a vampire experiences - the one that causes Humanity to drop from 1 to 0 and puts the vampire entirely and permanently under control of the Beast. Once a vampire enters Wassail, he is lost forever.

Sabiendo esto lo mejor que podemos hacer es buscar alguna edición en español del juego de rol y ver cómo lo han traducido. Así he encontrado [textos](http://webvampiro.com/vampiro-edad-oscura/la-bestia-y-la-muerte/) que hacen mención al "frenzy" como "frenesí", y dejan el término Wassail tal cual sin adaptar.

> También hay Vampiros que no escapan nunca del Frenesí, quedando convertidos en bestias irracionales que sólo buscan la destrucción. Este estado, conocido como Wassail, genera animales salvajes que son eliminados en cuanto es posible.

Así que mi recomendación es que lo dejes sin adaptar y con mayúscula inicial.